# Xcode 14 (on Ventura): "Failed to prevent system sleep during UI testing" when UNIT testing

Tags: xcode14

I'm running Xcode 14 beta 5 on macOS Ventura (13.0 Beta (22A5321d)) and when trying to run unit tests, not UI tests, plain old unit tests, I get this super annoying dialog when starting a test.

This is an SPM package, not an .xcodeproj.

[image]

If I click details, this is shown:

```
Details

Failed to prevent system sleep during UI testing. Error code: -536870211
Domain: IDEFoundationErrorDomain
Code: 1
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2022-08-17 20:06:42 +0000";
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 13.0 (Build 22A5321d)
Xcode 14.0 (21330) (Build 14A5294e)
Timestamp: 2022-08-17T22:06:42+02:00
```

Sometimes deleting derived data helps, sometimes not.

Any clues? I did not see this error in Xcode 14 beta 1 I think.

Comment: Xcode 14 beta with Ventura Beta has a bunch of issues. I have build issues all the time as well as archiving project issues, and have to clean and build all the time, especially during iOS development.

Comment: A shot in the dark, can you try: sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer.  In case you still have Xcode 13.4.1 installed and it's still half pointing to it.

Comment: @apollosoftware.org already repointed with xcode-select, might try to reinstall though. Bah.

Comment: @apollosoftware.org - I tried this and still get the same issue as the OP

Comment: Im having the same issue. I tried deleting derived data, installing Xcode 14 beta 6.  Nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

In terminal run: `sudo pmset schedule cancelall`

This fixed the issue for me on macOS Ventura Beta 5, Xcode 14 beta 6.

The answer came from this [comment](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/444501). It looks like a bug causes process powerd to issue too many assertions to pmset. This causes a problem when another process tries to create a PreventUserIdleSystemSleep assertion.